# Prestashop slider settings won't update

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, prestashop

So I've done a fresh install of Prestashop.

**Version:** 1.6.0.9

**Theme:** Prestashop default bootstrap theme

I'm trying to make the default slider full width.

To do this, I followed a mini tutorial which basically says you have to un-hook the theme configurator in the module position section leaving just the slider and then go into the slider settings and change the **max-width** to 1170px.

However, every time I change any of the values, **max-width**, **speed** or **pause** and press save, it doesn't actually save?

It just reverts to the original default values even though it states "The settings have been successfully updated."

Anyone know why the values aren't changing?

Comment: @Gorostas How do you expect me to provide you a code example of a Prestashop module? Showing you code of the plug in is irrelevant in this circumstance.

Comment: This is not answer to stackoverflow, please dont ask 'general' questions, provide us code problem, that we can assist you. If you have problem with Pretashop, ask their support

Comment: Hi,I am also facing the same problem. @Ashley did you find your solution for this? please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to your Phpmyadmin, click on the prestashop database then go to the *your database prefix*_configuration table and look for the HOME_SLIDER fields. To make this easier, if you click the name colum, it will sort them out alphabetically.

Now what you need to do is make sure there are no duplicate fields, there should be 4 in total. Provided you've deleted the duplicates or that you have no duplicates, change the HOME_SLIDERWIDTH to 1170 and press save.

Then just go to your back office and clear the cache and the changes should take effect. In the slider module settings, it will most likely have a blank value for the width so just leave that how it is and only change your images etc

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the tpl file of slider. First close all the div tag at the top of tpl file and again open the closed divs at the end.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the exact same problem here.
I was checking the db, trying to figure out where these settings come from.
The thing is that I beleive it is correct to have triple entries for each setting, because one is for specific shop group and shop id, one is for specific shop group, and one is "global" for all shops.
They all have to be there because of possible multistore use of prestashop.

When I change the settings in backoffice the setting with specific id_shop_group and specific id_shop **is** changed in the database.
So the problem is either:
 a) writing to db is wrong. Should write to all 3 fields if multistore is turned off.

b) reading from db is wrong. Should read the setting for my id_shop and my id_shop_group and not the setting for the unspecific global shop (with group and id null)

My understanding of Prestashop is still limited, but I will try to dig into this.
Someone that is more versed in module programming should probably be able to find the bug quickly, so any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Why the downvote?
Anyway, for those who are still trying to resolve this issue, I figured out that the homeslider settings were working correctly prior to updating the module. So I uninstalled it and deleted it and then downloaded fresh prestashop installation and moved the homeslider folder into my current installation. Works as expected now. I just have to watch out not to update it until they fix the bug.